Connect domain with github pages website with Jekyl theme to use as online portfolio
Please help me with know how about if we can make website using github pages and connect a new domain whilst skipping webhosting fees completely. please help if you have knowledge about it as i am looking to host jekyl theme for personal portfolio website.
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll

Yes, you can use a custom domain with GitHub pages, and the web hosting cost is completely free, as long as your website is static.
You can make your website with Jekyll, GitHub Pages is designed to work with jekyll
